# Proving that UB is transitive follows from B is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm really stuck as to how to prove that if B is a transitive set, it must be the case that the union of B is transitive as well. I guess I'm just a bit shaky on the concepts of proofs overall, but even though I can intuit that it should be the case, I'm not sure how I would go about proving it. I think maybe I've just looked at it for too long. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** If $B$ is transitive, then $x\in B\implies x\subseteq B$. Suppose that $y\in\bigcup B$. Then by definition $y\in x$ for some $x\in B$. Use the transitivity of $B$ to conclude that $y\subseteq\bigcup B$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand the hint: if x is a member of B it is also a subset and therefore the member y of ⋃B will be a member of some member of B and therefore that y will also be a member of B, but I don't see how you can conclude from that that y⊆⋃B

Comment: Nevermind, sorry, I get it! Thanks a lot.